# characterization of certain idealizers of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, modules

Consider two commutative rings with identity, $R$ and $S$ where $R$ is a principal ideal domain, $S$ is free and finitely-generated as an $R$-module and suppose
there is a $R$-module homomorphism $\phi:S \rightarrow R$.

For any ideal ${\mathfrak a}$ in $R$, the set of all $s \in S$ such that $\phi(s) \in {\mathfrak a}$ is an $R$-submodule of $S$, call it $S_{{\mathfrak a}}$.

I am interested in the set of all $s \in S$ such that $sS_{{\mathfrak a}} \subseteq S_{{\mathfrak a}}$.
It is easy to show that this set is a subring of $S$, but that is all I know about them.

As rschwieb wrote below in response to my more general earlier question, these are examples of idealizers.

I would like to understand the nature of these idealizers as a function of ${\mathfrak a}$ and $\phi$.
Even the simpler case when $R={\mathbb Z}$ and ${\mathfrak a}=(n)$ would help.
I am hoping that with so much structure available in these cases there may already be results available.

Does anyone know about these objects in such cases?
References too would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically an [idealizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealizer). Given an additively closed subset of a commutative ring, the idealizer is essentially is the largest subring in which the set is actually an ideal. In your case, you are looking at the idealizer in $S$ of $S_a$.

There is a cousin of this called a ["conductor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_%28ring_theory%29#Conductor) (or sometimes called a "transporter".) As you can tell from the wiki article, they're often used when looking at domains inside their field of fractions.

I remember both of these things were subsumed in the study of [residuated lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice), but I regret that I can't immediately bring the details to mind.

When you've got an $R$ module $M$ with two subsets $N,N'$, you can define the residual to be $(N:N')_R=\{r\in R\mid N'r\subseteq N\}$. Annihilators of modules are the special case $(\{0\}:N')=ann(N')$. (If you are in the mood, there are a lot of very general papers by Ward and Dilworth on residuated lattices.)

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer. I see what you mean and initially I was thinking there was something annihilator-like about this question, but had no success that way. A difference with the conductors and residuals you mention is that I am multiplying by elements in $S$ here, not $R$ -- recall that $S$ is an $R$-algebra. Thanks again and for improving the tags!

Comment: Dear @AaronW Honestly, all of the bells and whistles added around the question don't really help me find terms for it. All I know is that you're looking at $(S_a:S_a)_S$, in the notation I introduced. If you start here and look for places where people specialize to your conditions, then maybe you'll have better luck. Regards.

Comment: @AaronW Basically you are looking at an idealizer. The extra stuff about how you choose $S_a$ and $S$ being an $R$ module and $R$ being a PID is a pretty chimeric, and I would be pretty amazed if this entire situation fell under a single term :)

Comment: Thanks again, you are right that $(S_{{\mathfrak a}}:S_{{\mathfrak a}})_{S}$ is the object that I am looking at. I will try using "residual" and "conductor" as search words to find out more. It's ok that the specifics of the problem were not helpful to you. I was hoping they would be helpful to those who know more than me and that ideally in such special cases, nice things happen. Thanks.